# Meaning "s'thing"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Today I have met such sentence, "Do s’thing of your own free will". I for the first time see such construction "s'noun". Unfortunately I could not find its meaning out. I suppose, it says about plural number. So, could somebody explain me it?

Comment: _S'thing_ is a (not particularly common) abbreviation of _something_.

Comment: Oh, thank you! So, it's an obsolete form, isn't it?

Comment: Where'd you find it?

Comment: No, I don't think it's obsolete. I just don't think there is a generally used abbreviation for _something_. I have seen _s.t._, and _stg_, but I've often had the sense that these were being used by people whose first language wasn't English. English speakers traditionally didn't tend to abbreviate _something_ very much.

Comment: `s'thing`, `sth`, etc are abbreviations for 'something' often found in dictionaries and grammar books.

Comment: I found this phrase there http://ngoaingu.vimaru.edu.vn/wp-content/uploads/documents/Emailing-English-Prepositions-Explained.pdf
p.225